# Match the closest possible node in neo4j

Tags: time, neo4j, cypher

I have a time tree which is granulated to 5 min intervals. I have no problem while trying to match the exact minute . But in few cases, i might be searching for a minute which is not exactly matching the node. For ex. if i want to match 10:05 i can. But if the input is 10.03 i get no result. I have epoch times added to the minute node. I wanted to return the closest minute node available for the given input (if its 10.03 then return 10.05). how do i achieve this?

```
MATCH (startMinute:Minute {epoch:apoc.date.parse('2018-04-12T16:33', 'ms',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")}) return startMinute
```

My Model is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuCYY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to always round up the time:

```
MATCH (startMinute:Minute {epoch:
  (apoc.date.parse('2018-04-12T16:32', 'ms',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm") + 29999)/300000*300000})
RETURN startMinute;
```

Or, if you want to round to nearest:

```
MATCH (startMinute:Minute {epoch:
  (apoc.date.parse('2018-04-12T16:32', 'ms',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm") + 150000)/300000*300000})
RETURN startMinute;
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much :)